# Create date variable that is either 31 days after a certain date, or is the maximum date per ID

Tags: r, date, variables

I have data that looks something like this:

```
ID    Event    Date
A     0        2015-01-01
A     0        2015-02-01
A     1        2015-03-30
B     0        2016-02-28
B     0        2016-03-30
B     0        2016-04-30
C     0        2015-01-01
```

I'd like to create a variable called "Date2" so that if someone's Event is 1, their new date is 31 days after the corresponding date in which their Event==1. However, if an individual never has Event==1 (as in individuals B and C), I would like their dates set as the last date observed. My desired output is as follows:

```
ID    Event    Date          Date2
A     0        2015-01-01    2015-05-01
A     0        2015-02-01    2015-05-01
A     1        2015-03-31    2015-05-01
B     0        2016-02-28    2016-04-30
B     0        2016-03-31    2016-04-30
B     0        2016-04-30    2016-04-30
C     0        2015-01-01    2015-01-01
```

So far, I have tried:

```
setDT(data)
data[, Date2 := max(Date)]
data[data[Event == 1, .I[1], by=c("ID")]$V1, Date2:= as.Date(Date[which(Event == 1)], format="%Y-%m-%d") + 31]
```

While Date2 for whomever has Event==1 is correct, my Date2 for all others ends up being the maximum Date from the entire data set, so 2016-04-30, in this case.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one row where `Event==1L`, you can use `if` in `j`  as follows:

```
data[, Date2 := if (any(Event==1L)) Date[Event==1] + 31L else max(Date), by=.(ID)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I made some changes based on some other conditions I required and this code worked for the most part... There are some issues with my output, but for now this is the best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the `by` parameter of your data.table to `ID` and add the columns `Event` and `Date` to the required computation `Date2`. So doing this

```
setDT(data)
data[,.(Event,Date,Date2=if(sum(Event)!=0) {Date[.N]+31} else {Date[.N]}),by=ID]
```

The result is

```
   ID Event       Date      Date2
1:  A     0 2015-01-01 2015-05-01
2:  A     0 2015-02-01 2015-05-01
3:  A     1 2015-03-31 2015-05-01
4:  B     0 2016-02-28 2016-04-30
5:  B     0 2016-03-30 2016-04-30
6:  B     0 2016-04-30 2016-04-30
7:  C     0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a function that rips out what we want for a specific ID, then we'll apply it piece-wise to the data frame, and shove it all back together at the end :)

First, so we're explicit, let's make sure the `Date` column is stored as type `Date`. If you're unsure, use `class(df$Date)` to check.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Now for the fun stuff.

**The function**

```
date_adder <- function(
  df
){

  #Look for a 1 in the dataset
  event_match <- match(1, df$Event)

  #If we found a match
  if(!is.na(event_match)){

    return(df$Date[event_match] + 31)

  } else { #If there was no match

    #Find the biggest date they have on record

    #I took last as 'biggest'
    #If you want last in data frame, use nrow(df) instead
    last_element <- which.max(df$Date)

    return(df$Date[last_element])
  }

}
```

This function takes advantage of a data frame for a specific ID, i.e. it just has a list of Events and Dates. If it finds an event, it adds 31 to that day and returns it, otherwise it returns the latest date it can fine (I've left a comment for if this were not your intention).

To make this function usable, just execute it like any other code.

**List of IDs and Date2s**

```
date_list <- plyr::ddply(df, "ID", date_adder)
```

This takes advantage of a function from the `plyr` package that applies a function to subsets of a data frame. here I subset on `ID` and apply our `date_adder` function. So for each ID it does what I've described up top. It returns a data frame like this.

```
  ID         V1
1  A 2015-04-30
2  B 2016-04-30
3  C 2015-01-01
```

I assume this is right, as `2015-04-30` is 31 days later, not the first of May like you indicated.

**Piece it together**

```
df$Date2 <- date_list[match(df$ID, date_list$ID),2]
```

With all that done we just sew it together based on the matching IDs. And voila, you've got a solution :)

```
  ID Event       Date      Date2
1  A     0 2015-01-01 2015-04-30
2  A     0 2015-02-01 2015-04-30
3  A     1 2015-03-30 2015-04-30
4  B     0 2016-02-28 2016-04-30
5  B     0 2016-03-30 2016-04-30
6  B     0 2016-04-30 2016-04-30
7  C     0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you! I can follow the logic of this so have tried it, but am stuck on the step to actually create the list. I get this error:

Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths